# Getting size of anonymous struct within a structure

Tags: c

I need to create a structure with a particular size for memory access optimization.  Under normal circumstances a "reserved" field is used to pad out the structure to be a particular size.  I am looking for a way to define an anonymous structure so I can use its size to pad out the reserved field such that I don't have to constantly update the reserve padding size.

One way of implementing this would be

```
typedef struct _xferStructure_t
{
    struct anonymous
    {
        uint32_t field1;
        uint32_t field2;
        uint32_t field3;
    } _;
  
  uint8_t reserved[1024 - sizeof(struct anonymous)];
    
} xferStructure_t;



int main()
{
    xferStructure_t xferData = {  ._.field1 = 1, ._.field2 = 2, ._.field3 = 3 };
    
    printf("Field 1 = %d", xferData._.field1);
    printf("Reserved = %ld", sizeof(xferData.reserved));

    return 0;
}
```

Ideally, I would like to access the three fields in the anonymous structure without the declaring it.  So, something like

```
typedef struct _xferStructure_t
{
    struct anonymous
    {
        uint32_t field1;
        uint32_t field2;
        uint32_t field3;
    };
  
  uint8_t reserved[1024 - sizeof(struct anonymous)];
    
} xferStructure_t;



int main()
{
    xferStructure_t xferData = {  .field1 = 1, .field2 = 2, .field3 = 3 };
    
    printf("Field 1 = %d", xferData.field1);
    printf("Reserved = %ld", sizeof(xferData.reserved));

    return 0;
}
```

The second implementation doesn't work, but it there a way to implemented this structure without having to declare the anonymous within the xfer structure?

Comment: I marked one duplicate but have some memory of another, with possibly additional information. I am not finding it at the moment. Maybe somebody else can.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to work, using an anonymous union and an anonymous struct. It also doesn't require you to calculate the size of the padding:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct {
    union {
        struct {
            uint32_t field1;
            uint32_t field2;
            uint32_t field3;
        };
        char fill[1024];
    };
} xferStructure_t;

int main(void)
{
    xferStructure_t xferData = {  .field1 = 1, .field2 = 2, .field3 = 3 };

    _Static_assert(sizeof xferData == 1024);

    printf("Field 1 = %d\n", xferData.field1);
    //printf("Reserved = %ld", sizeof(xferData.reserved));

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Field 1 = 1
```

Tested on gcc 11.4.0 on Ubuntu 22.04. The `_Static_assert()` can be changed to `static_assert()` once you're compiling with a C23 compiler.

Comment: Paranoia suggests adding a static assert to make sure that the size of the complete structure is the same size as `char fill[1024]`.

Answer (score 0):

Small workaround:

```
#define S1      struct     \
    { \
        uint32_t field1;\
        uint32_t field2;\
        uint32_t field3;\
    }


typedef struct _xferStructure_t
{
    S1;
  
    uint8_t reserved[1024-sizeof(S1)];
    
} xferStructure_t;



int main(void)
{
    xferStructure_t xferData = {  .field1 = 1, .field2 = 2, .field3 = 3 };
    
    printf("Field 1 = %d", xferData.field1);
    printf("Reserved = %ld", sizeof(xferData.reserved));

    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/dEP4Woa4K